# Simplify Switch Statement in following code

Tags: c#, switch-statement, code-size

How can i make this code to be much smaller in size and more efficient :) ..?.
I have made it so far, from a bigger old code, but i think it's still huge.

```
if (affix == Mod.Affix)
{
    Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.White);

    switch (levels)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            Size level = Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.Yellow);
            if (level != new Size()) 
            { 
                position.Y += level.Height; 
            }
        } break;

        case 2:
        {
            Size level = Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.Red);
            if (level != new Size()) 
            {
                position.Y += level.Height; 
            }
        } break;

        case 3:
        {
            Size level = Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.Green);
            if (level != new Size()) 
            { 
                position.Y += level.Height; 
            }
        } break;

        default:
            Size nextLevel = Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.Black);

            if (nextLevel != new Size()) 
            { 
                position.Y += nextLevel.Height;
            } 
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish when doing `if(level != new Size())`?

Comment: @Matias Cicero - To align the text on the same position.

Comment: In case 1-3, all you need to maintain is the `Color`. The rest of the code can be moved outside the switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary to map levels to colors:

```
private static Dictionary<int, Color> levelColors = new Dictionary<int, Color>
{
    { 1, Color.Yellow },
    { 2, Color.Red },
    { 3, Color.Green }
};
```

Then you can change your method to just be this:

```
Color color;
if (!levelColors.TryGetValue(levels, out color)) // try and get the color for the level
{
    color = Color.Black; // Default to black if no level color found
}

Size level = Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, color);
if (level != new Size())
{
    position.Y += level.Height;
}
```

That way, you don't need to modify the method as you add/alter level colors, you just update the dictionary.

Comment: This looks like the best solution, and i can add later more levels if i need. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
Color color = new Color();
switch (levels)
{
    case 1:
        color = Color.Yellow;
        break;

    case 2:
        color = Color.Red;
        break;

    case 3:
        color = Color.Green;
        break;

    default:
        color = Color.Black;
        break;
}
Size level = Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, color);
if (level != new Size()) // ???
{ 
    position.Y += level.Height;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing the same code for each colour, try this:

```
switch (levels)
{
    case 1:
        AddHeight(Color.Yellow);
        break;
    case 2:
        AddHeight(Color.Red);
        break;
    case 3:
        AddHeight(Color.Green);
        break;
    default:
        AddHeight(Color.Black);
        break;
}

public void AddHeight(Color color){
    Size level = Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, color);
    if (level != new Size()) // ???
    { 
        position.Y += level.Height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a predifined mapping "level_to_color" like (for example initialzed in static constructor):

```
Dictionary<int,Color> _levelToColor = new Dictionary<int,Color>();
_levelToColor.Add(1, Color.Yellow);
_levelToColor.Add(2, Color.Red);
_levelToColor.Add(3, Color.Green);
```

And then your code might look like:

```
Color color = _levelToColor.ContainsKey( level ) ?  _levelToColor[level] : Color.Black;
Size level = Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, color);
position.Y += level.Height;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (affix == Mod.Affix)
{
    Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.White);

    Size level =
         (levels == 1) ? Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.Yellow) 
         :((levels == 2) ? Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.Red) 
         : ((levels == 3) ? Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.Green) 
         : Graphics.DrawText(text, textSize, position, Color.Black)));

    if (level != new Size()) 
    { 
        position.Y += nextLevel.Height;
    }
}
```

Comment: That quickly gets difficult to read, nested ternary operators are fairly evil!

Comment: Yes, I agree, but he asked for shorter -- I am not a fan of short for the reason of readability.

Comment: I think my solution is readable enough for his specific scenario since there are only 4 cases. If it were larger, I would have suggested something different. My point was that I value readability over number of lines. This pattern could certainly become messy, but in this case still seems appropriate.